# Parse PDF including vector font

Tags: php, pdf, ocr

I have some PDF documents which I need to convert into text using a web interface (via browser). All this on a server which runs the usual stuff (apache, php, mysql, ...).

Now ... the tricky part is, that these PDF documents were generated using some vector fonts, making it virtually impossible to parse the PDF file using standard methods.

Two questions:

1. Does anybody know how to parse such a PDF document including vector fonts?
2. Is there anything out there like OCR software, which I could include in my PHP code (as class, library, ...)?

pdfinfo says:

```
root@gan:~/workspace# pdfinfo comp.pdf
Producer:       Aladdin Ghostscript TESTER RELEASE 6.22
Tagged:         no
Pages:          2
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595 x 842 pts (A4)
File size:      56482 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.2
```

This might be intersting:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17663/how-to-know-if-a-pdf-file-is-compressed-or-not-and-to-uncompress-it

```
root@gan:~/workspace# strings comp.pdf | grep /Filter
<</Length 6 0 R/Filter /FlateDecode>>
<</Length 150 0 R/Filter /FlateDecode>>
```

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean with *vector fonts, making it virtually impossible to parse the PDF file using standard methods*? PDF fonts normally are defined by vector operations. You might want to supply a sample PDF.

Comment: Here we go ... nothing of the text shown can be seen using an text (or hex) editor. http://www.dropbox.com/s/6yo378t1mu4j74b/1400769600930.HEI-dmz2-prd-crewlink.2336.idp.pdf

Comment: @geohei PDF files are usually compressed or encrypted, so that is the case for most of the PDF files out there.

Comment: Original posting edited. The PDF not compressed nor optimized.

Comment: The sample file you provided does not contain the information for normal text extraction. Its only font uses a custom encoding and does not use standard character names in that encoding nor does it offer a **ToUnicode** mapping. Thus, you'll indeed have to use some OCR solution. I don't know enough of OCR solutions to help on that subject.

Comment: For my info ... how can you see in my sample that (1.) there is no information for text extraction and (2.) that it does not offer ToUnicode mapping (whatever that means). Where can I find information about PDF structuring and OCR processing regarding PDFs (site, forum, ...)? Thanks

Comment: Off topic ... how can I configure this site to send me an e-mail as soon as someone writes a comment? Thanks